# How to prevent Iframe tags from showing?

Tags: html, iframe

It has come to my attention that if you turn off Javascript, on Google Chrome(at least), the text `<iframe>` and its attributes are visible when Javascript is turned off and leave an odd appearance on the page.

You can test this on sites that use it. [For example.](https://www.evernote.com/market#) *turn JS off to see*

Is this a bug? Is it considered a type of script, and should it be wrapped with "noscript"?

I'm sure companies that use iframes are unaware, I've noticed it on some Google pages too, there must be someway to get around it.

Answer (score 1):

i'm working with iframes but i'm not aware about this problem, but here is a hint if it helps.

You can start the page with iframe hidden:

```
<iframe style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

and once page load you can show them, then if javascript is enabled this line will run and will show them otherwise will kept hidden:

```
$("iframe").show();    //jQuery
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').style.display = 'block'; //Pure Javascript
```

Comment: I don't believe your *exact* example would work because the actual "iframe" element isn't considered anything but regular text. I believe if you make a wrapper for it( like nest it in a div), then maybe that approach would work.

Comment: can you give me example for your iframe? or you can set CSS for all iframes to be hidden iframe{display:none;} if you can't control them and continue the same way to enable

Comment: If you turn off javascript and view the example you'll notice that the entire Iframe is in text form. That means it hasn't registered with the document and is considered plain text. If you were to use CSS it wouldn't be able to find the "iframe" because no such tag exists. If you added the inline style "display:none" it would just show the iframe with that exact text inside of it.